# Assistance in how to use Vue to check to see if the page prop is set

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have been trying to implement the spatie package Laravel-permissions. In doing so I have created some inertia page props to check if a user has a permission on the front end.

I have been able to create a middleware to check if a user has a role, and then set page props from there as you can see below in the screenshot on the `is_foo` props.

When I was doing this I noticed in the user props that there is already a roles sub key set that contains an array of strings for each of the roles a user has been set. I am not sure where these are being passed to through inertia to the props within Laravel.

[image]

In this screenshot you can see both the area where I have set the props to capture the user roles & further down the props array set by the package.

I am stuck & unable to work out how I can do the following:

1 - check if a page prop existing in the user > roles array that contains the name "Admin"

2 - use that in a v-if statement to display a link to the admin page.

I know the way I have been doing it works, but using the props that are generated by the spatie package is much cleaner so please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there is a role with the name Admin in a computed property, like this:

```
computed: {
  adminExists() {
    return this.user.roles && this.user.roles.find((e) => e.name == "Admin");
  }
}
```

Then you can use that value in the `v-if` statement like this:

```
<a href="#" v-if="adminExists">Link Label</a>
```

Comment: The solution you posted does not work, the syntax is not correct and throws back errors.

Comment: Can you please specify what error you see?

Comment: That is another error, please show your code where the error is being reported.

Comment: It was all good, my mistake. Your solution works just fine! Thanks.